# using x86_64 FPU with out checking for irq_fpu_usable, if xsaveopts instructions is supported by processor

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, x86, aes, x86-64

In x86(_64) irq context (both soft and hard irq) saving FPU context is expensive activity. So before using FPU, irq_fpu_usable check is done.

Below are my questions:

1. If the processor support xsaveopts instruction, is still saving
   FPU is an expensive activity ?
2. What issues we may face if we save the FPU context in irq context.

Comment: [tag:crypt] is something different and has little to no followers, try and make your question as visible as possible, e.g. by mentioning the language/runtime.

Answer (score 2):

The `XSAVEOPTS` only prevents entire FPU register sets (x87, XMM, YMM) from being saved, and it's very likely that x87 and XMM registers will need to be saved. So its still going to be an expensive operation.

Note that the purpose of the Linux kernel function `irq_fpu_usable` is to determine if its permissible to use the FPU at all. It doesn't test whether using the FPU would require the expensive activity of saving FPU context as your question implies.

If `irq_fpu_usable` is true and you wrap your use of the FPU in in `kernel_fpu_begin` and `kernel_fpu_end` then using the FPU in in IRQ context should be safe. It might however be slower than alternative code that doesn't use the FPU at all.

You shouldn't try to save the FPU context yourself, if that's what you mean by your second question.